# Get all the Booleans of Model accordingly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a *blog application*, and I am trying to get all the Booleans of the `Profile` model. I tried to make a list of Booleans before, but then it was not meeting the requirements.

File *models.py*

```
class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    second_boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    third_boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

File *views.py*

```
def page(request):
    All_Booleans = Profile.objects.filter()

    context = {'Booleans_List'}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

I also tried **F** of `from django.db.models import F` like:

```
All_Booleans = Profile.objects.filter(F(first_boolean=request.user) | F(second_boolean=request.user))
```

But it is showing:

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_boolean'

**What am I trying to do? -**

I am trying to get all the Boolean fields of `Profile Model` of request.user

But how can I do it ?

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you aim to do. If you exclude booleans that are true, you are left with a list of zero, one, two or three bools, and all these bools will be `False`. But then it is not clear to me what you want to do with that list. Furthermore `request.user.profile` will not work, since a user can be related to many `Profile`s in your modeling.

Comment: I will track every `Boolean`, And if it is not going to work then, How can i get all the `Booleans of a Model` ?

Comment: @Van see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Not to mention we don't know what X is here, I fail to understand even the Y here. Please add more details to your question what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Van: I simply do not understand what you want to do. Depending on that it might work. But you can simply pass the `profile` to the template, and render the booleans there. But I think right now the first problem to fix is retrieving the `.profile` of a `User`. Since you use a `ForeignKey`, and not a `OneToOneField`, this means that there is no `.profile` added to the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the `Profile` for the logged in user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def page(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'profile': profile})
```

In the template you can then render the Boolean fields of that `profile` with:

```
one: {{ profile.first_boolean }}
two: {{ profile.second_boolean }}
three: {{ profile.third_boolean }}
```

You can add the Booleans to a list and use these in the template as well with:

```
@login_required
def page(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    data = [profile.first_boolean, profile.second_boolean, profile.third_boolean]
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'profile': profile, 'data': data})
```

Then you can, for example, render this with:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly.

For more information, you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks But I think you didn't understand something , I am trying to get all the Boolean Fields like `queryset`, Like :- `[<first_boolean:True>,<second_boolean:False>]` Just Boolean Fields. But I liked your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` advice

Comment: @Van: you can put these into a list (see edited answer), and for example enumerate over these, but then the data of the *name* of the field is gone. You can also construct a list of 2-tuples for example `[('first_boolean, profile.first_boolean)]`, etc. but it is still not clear to me why you want to do that: usually if you make different columns, it makes not much sense to put these as individual elements in a list. If that is necessary, then often it means something is wrong with the modeling.

Comment: I will track every `Boolean Field` one by one and monitor the requirements to turn the Boolean Field `True`. How can I access first element of list in this loop, I tried `.0` and `.first` in template but it is not showing anything

Comment: @Van: in the loop the `item` is each time an element of the list. You can access the first item of the list with `{{ data.0 }}`, but that is equivalent to `{{ profile.first_boolean }}`, hence it is unclear why you need a list.